# Подписан ли человек на группу

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

Подскажите как реализовать, у меня стоит на сайте код сообщества "Вконтакте" вот код:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?113"></script>

<!-- VK Widget -->
<div id="vk_groups"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {mode: 0, width: "672", height: "200", color1: 'FFFFFF', color2: '2B587A', color3: '5B7FA6'}, 71205899);
</script>
```

Подскажите как получить ответ от сервера "Вконтакте" что человек подписан или нет, допустим если человек подписан на группу ответ = 1, а если не подписан или не состоит в ней то ответ = 0, подскажите возможно такое сделать ?

Answer (score 1):

Есть специальный метод api ВКонтакта [`groups.isMember()`](https://vk.com/dev/groups.isMember), который показывает, является ли чел Участником группы.

Но чтобы получить ВКонтактовский id посетителя вашего сайта, понадобится сделать на вашем сайте [вход через ВКонтакте](https://vk.com/dev/Auth).